# Swift создание действия при нажатие на ячейку tableview

Tags: xcode, swift

Есть `tableView` встроенная во `viewController`.

Каким методом можно совершить действие при нажатии на ячейку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        //Ваши действия 
    }
```

Нашел.